# What's the best way to organize a dictionary to exchange data?

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, static

In unity I have a dictionary where I keep a lot of data. I'll need to access the data, read it, and sometimes *overwrite it*. I have it inside a class that's written more or less like

```
public class myClass
{
    public int myNumber;
    public string myString;
}

public class MyData : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Dictionary<string, myClass> someData = new Dictionary<string, myClass>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        someData.Add("one", new myClass() { myNumber = 1, myString = "first" });
        someData.Add("two", new myClass() { myNumber = 2, myString = "second" });
        someData.Add("three", new myClass() { myNumber = 3, myString = "third" });
    }
}
```

To avoid having to call `gameObject.GetComponent<MyData>().someData` everytime I need the Dictionary's data (since I need it across many GameObjects and scripts) I was thinking about setting the Dictionary as `static` which would allow to reference it with `MyData.someData` (and hopefully having better performance):

```
public static Dictionary<string, myClass> someData = new Dictionary<string, myClass>();
```

However, when I try accessing the Dictionary data in the `Start` method of other classes (that should therefore be executed after the `Awake` method of `MyData`), `MyData.someData` is always `null`. I don't know if it has something to do with the calling order or if there's a problem with setting the Dictionary as static. I'm not experienced enough to understand.

Is `static` the correct usage here for the Dictionary? Or are there better solutions?

Moreover, if there's a Dictionary I only want to read but never modify, are there ways to define it so that it remains immutable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `SomeData` a static field and then you can call it as `MyData.SomeData` throughout your app.  You need to explicitly call the `Awake()` method in order to add the three `MyClass` instances to `SomeData` dictionary. You can create a static constructor and call the `Awake()` inside it.

```
public class MyData : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Dictionary<string, myClass> someData = new Dictionary<string, myClass>();

    static MyData()
    {
        Awake();
    }

    private static void Awake()
    {
        someData.Add("one", new myClass() { myNumber = 1, myString = "first" });
        someData.Add("two", new myClass() { myNumber = 2, myString = "second" });
        someData.Add("three", new myClass() { myNumber = 3, myString = "third" });
    }
}
```

There is a readonly dictionary in .NET 4.5...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlydictionary-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 1):

instantiate the dictionary in Awake.
add items to the dictionary in Start.
Awake is always called before start so this will guarantee your dictionary is initialized before trying to access it.

Comment: Thanks! But wouldn't it be better to instantiate it outside `Awake` and adding items in `Awake`? Isn't it even faster regarding order of execution?

Comment: awake happens before anything else and you need to instantiate it before adding items